# revert back to capturing mode in camera when an image captured is dicarded

Tags: android

I use camera intent as follows

```
mCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            imageurl="";
            Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            //startActivityForResult(pickPhoto , 1);
            startActivityForResult(takePicture, CAMERA_REQUEST);


                dialog.cancel();


        }
    });
```

but when an image captured is discarded/cancel instead of pressing save the user will be directed back to activity.Is there a way to handle this to stay back in capture mode even if cancel/dismiss is pressed

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to call

> cameraObject.startPreview();

to start it again after you discard the picture

Comment: I went an another way in onResult()                                                    if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode==0){
       Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    //startActivityForResult(pickPhoto , 1);
             startActivityForResult(takePicture, CAMERA_REQUEST);
      }